# How do I get the output of "subprocess.check_output()" when it involves "$$"?

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I want to get the string output of executing `ps -p $$ -oargs=` through python.

When I try this:

```
subprocess.check_output("ps -p $$ -oargs=", shell=True)
```

I get "ps -p 9017 -oargs=" but when I try `ps -p $$ -oargs=` directly in a shell I get "-bash". How do I get "-bash" through python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's doing exactly what you asked it to do, filtering the `ps` to only output information on the process with the PID of the shell that's running it (that's what `$$` means).

If you want information on the Python session itself, you need to pass the PID of the Python process itself, e.g. (removing the `shell=True` wrapping since you don't need it for `$$` here):

```
subprocess.check_output(["ps", "-p", str(os.getpid()), "-oargs="])
```

Make sure to `import os` at the top of your file so you have access to `os.getpid`.